# Chart.js how to inser values from json

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I have an issue inserting in Chart.js only two values(timestamp and cpu telemetry) from external JSON(which is located remotely on VPS). In Console all data loaded correctly, my code is:

```js
var theCpuUrl = "http://" + address + "/api/metric/cpu";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var ctx = document.getElementById('cpuchart').getContext('2d');

var cpuchart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: '......',
    datasets: [{
      label: 'cpu',
      data: [80, 70, 80, 20, 10, 50],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }],
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});

httpGetAsync(theCpuUrl, function(data, status) {
  var myData = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < myData[0].length; i++) {
    let time = myData[0][i].timestamp;
    let value = myData[0][i].cpu;
  }
});
xmlhttp.open("GET", theCpuUrl, true);
console.log(xmlhttp.readyState);
```

This code is also connected to `global.js` with next code:

```js
var address = "192.168.13.60:12345"

function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Please somebody can you explain me how do I draw data on Y and X axis.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. The issue is coming because you have initialised the chart first `new Chart` and you're getting the **updated** values asynchronously. You can solve this problem by initialising chart once you have received the data.

e.g.

```js
httpGetAsync(theCpuUrl, function(data, status) {
  var myData = JSON.parse(data);
   // storing time and values 
   let time=[], value=[];
   for (var i = 0; i < myData[0].length; i++) {
     time.push(myData[0][i].timestamp);
     value.push(myData[0][i].cpu);
   }
   // now you have data in time and value array ready
   --> here call the "new Chart" which you're calling above. <--
});
```

Comment: Hope that worked for you @JohnyMnemonick. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.